# Embedding Python, works in main() but not in WinMain()

Tags: python, c++, c, windows, python-embedding

I am embedding Python 3.4 into my application written in C++. When I enter the program with main() all works great, but when I use WinMain() it crashes. When Py_Initialize is called in main() everything works but in WinMain it fails. I am guessing it has something to do with the console not being there as WinMain() does not create a console.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a stack trace or anything?

Comment: @FatalError Python is not showing any errors, it crashes when Py_ Initizilaze calls abort because of an error. It seems to be giving this error: EDIT: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams.

Comment: `Py_Initialize` works fine in a GUI app. After all, pythonw has no console.

Comment: I thought so too, but it seems to only work with a console. When in WinMain() Py_Initialize gives the error: Can't initialize sys standard streams.

Comment: Is there something in WinMain() that could cause Py_Initialize to break? All that is different is that there is no console, right?

Comment: OK, don't believe me then!

Comment: @CaptainPicard: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant to collect a C++ stacktrace in your debugger and see where exactly it's crashing.  That might help you figure out why.

Comment: @FatalError, thanks for showing up again! The call stack/stack trace in visual studio is giving me this on the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/loofim16dpn8its/stack.txt

Comment: It seems to crash in pythonrun.c on line 462-465 python throws the error Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams. It seems that initstdio is failing with a return value of -1. NOTE: I did not write pythonrun.c it is part of the python source code.

Comment: And more debugging shows that in pythonrun.c line 1223 is where the error happens, in the function create_stdio.

Comment: related: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/dev-python/pjzDQPXGJB8